# Null Pointer Exception in Prepared Statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I ran in to a problem while trying to get data from my sql server where they give a null point exception at prepared statement. I'm sure this must be a noob question but please do help :)

this is the method i'm calling

```
public void notification(){
    int MachCode = 1721;
    try{
        String sql ="Select TimeOn from PRODUCTIONS_MONITOR where MachCode='"+MachCode+"'";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            arrCount.add(rs.getInt(1));

        }

        for(int i=0;i<arrCount.size();i++){

             Count = Count + arrCount.get(i);

        }

        if(Count % 10 == 0){

            System.out.println("Time = " + Count);

        }

    }catch(SQLException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

and here is my db connection

```
  public static Connection ConnecrDb() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 

       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.228.59.2:1433;databaseName=dbNautilus;user=SA;password=KreedaIntimo@2017;");

        System.out.println("Connected to database !");

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Sql Exception :" + sqle.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception :" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: what's the complete error returned?

Comment: Is this yout final code? 

Your connecrDb method is returning null, not the con object.

Comment: @DiogoSilvério this solved my problem thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ConnecrDb()` method assigns the new `Connection` object to a *local variable* named `con`, and then **never use it**.

The method then returns `null`.

You didn't show how to method was called, but it really doesn't matter, because the `con` *field* used by `notification()` method is either unassigned (and hence `null`), or assigned the `null` return value from `ConnecrDb()`, so it is `null` either way.

Given that, why are you confused the value is `null` and causes a `NullPointerException`?

---

*Other general comment about your code:*

- If `MachCode` is an integer, then why are you quoting it in SQL, i.e. why `where MachCode='"+MachCode+"'";` and not `where MachCode="+MachCode;`?
- If you're using `PreparedStatement`, why not use `?` parameter markers, as they are intended to be used?
- You should use try-with-resources when using JDBC.
- Java naming convention is for variable names to start with lowercase letter.

Your code should be:

```
int machCode = 1721;
String sql = "select TimeOn from PRODUCTIONS_MONITOR where MachCode = ?";
try (PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    pst.setInt(1, machCode);
    try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            arrCount.add(rs.getInt(1));
        }
    }
}
// rest of code here
```